# How do I circular shift some characters/bits?

Tags: string, perl, shift

I need to circular shift some characters/bit using Perl

For example, with the following input (reversing character strings):

```
1010
1110
hello
```

I need to obtain:

```
0101
0111
olleh
```

How do I achieve this using Perl?

Comment: Is that circular shifting or are you just using the [`reverse`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?perlfunc#reverse) operation?

Comment: And you are working with chars, not bits!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, if you really want to circular shift values, it's easy to write a function that does it with arbitrary lists for training:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

# circular shift lists
sub circular {
    my ($i, @values) = @_;
    return @values[ map +($_ + $i) % @values => 0 .. $#values ];
}

say circular  4, 1 .. 9;                # 567891234
say circular -2, 1 .. 9;                # 891234567
say circular  3, split '' => 'hello';   # lohel
```

A few words of explanation for the `return` line of `circular`:

```
return @values[ ... ];
```

We're returning an array slice of `@values` here, which means we evaluate it with a list of indices and return the list of values.

```
map ... => 0 .. $#values
```

We're returning a list of values here that we calculate from all indices of @values, 0 is the first, `$#values` is the last.

```
+($_ + $i) % @values
```

This is what we do with these indices. The `+` sign is only used to tell perl that the parantheses are not the argument paratheses for `map`. We add $i to the index and to prevent that it becomes `> $#values` we modulo divide it by the length of `@values`. Note that it's not important to call `length @values` here because `%` evaluates its second operand in scalar context and arrays in scalar context evaluate to their length.

I leave it up to you as a simple exercise to convert your things like `hello` or `1110` to lists and back to scalars.

Comment: Thank you, this is more than perfect for what I was looking for. Still learning, so I'm grateful you took the time to explain the mechanics to me as well!

Answer (score 3):

Seems like you want to reverse a string and not circular shifting!

```
$string=reverse($string);
```